# Number of fermions in Fermi-Hubbard model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, fermions

This is the Fermi-Hubbard model for a system of $L$ sites.

$$\hat H = -t \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}
^L (c^+_ic_{i+1} + h.c.) +V\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}^L n_in_j.$$

By looking at this equation, how do we know/determine how many fermions there are in the system? How many particles are there hopping and interacting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hamiltonian in your question is a many-body Hamiltonian (written in the language of creation and annihilation operators). It applies to any number of particles. As the sum goes from 1 to $L$, there are just $L$ possible states to fill and then the maximum number of fermions is $2L$ (the factor of two comes from spin-degeneracy, assuming spin 1/2).

Note that there are only particle number conserving terms, of the form
$$c^\dagger_i c_j$$
or its complex conjugate. The action of the operator on the left destroys a fermion in position $j$ but the operator on the right creates a new electron in position $i$. Every annihilation operation is followed by a creation operation and viceversa.

Given an initial condition with a number of fermions from 0 to $2L$, the number of particles will remain constant.

Comment: thank you for your reply! it's very well explained

Comment: This answer seems to assume the canonical ensemble instead of the grand canonical ensemble.

Comment: what happens if grand canonical ensemble is assumed? to we meet to add an extra term (--> chemical potential)?

Comment: @B.Brekke it doesn't matter which ensemble one uses: one cannot know the number of particles from the second quantized Hamiltonian. One needs to supplement it by specifying the ensemble and the number of particles or the chemical potential - depending on the ensemble used. Hubbard Hamiltonian is often specified as being at *half-filling* or *3/4-filling* etc. which means the number of fermions per site (and implies the canonical ensemble).

Comment: I agree. However, if one were to interpret this Hamiltonian within the GCE with the chemical potential set to zero, one could answer the question with an expectation value of the filling. But maybe that is not what the OP is searching for.